# connect to database in eclipse rcp

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse Rcp for JAVA what is the best method to show the data of table in our form and how can u  please tell me in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eclipse JFace Table - Tutorial** 
http://vogella.de/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use JFACE table viewers. Simple but relevent examples are provided in Vogella's site.